# Haskell - Maybe Either

Tags: haskell, either

```
-- | Convert a 'Maybe a' to an equivalent 'Either () a'. Should be inverse
-- to 'eitherUnitToMaybe'.
maybeToEitherUnit :: Maybe a -> Either () a
maybeToEitherUnit a = error "Not yet implemented: maybeToEitherUnit"

-- | Convert a 'Either () a' to an equivalent 'Maybe a'. Should be inverse
-- to 'maybeToEitherUnit'.
eitherUnitToMaybe :: Either () a -> Maybe a
eitherUnitToMaybe = error "Not yet implemented: eitherUnitToMaybe"

-- | Convert a pair of a 'Bool' and an 'a' to 'Either a a'. Should be inverse
-- to 'eitherToPairWithBool'.
pairWithBoolToEither :: (Bool,a) -> Either a a
pairWithBoolToEither = undefined  -- What should I do here?

-- | Convert an 'Either a a' to a pair of a 'Bool' and an 'a'. Should be inverse
-- to 'pairWithBoolToEither'.
eitherToPairWithBool :: Either a a -> (Bool,a)
eitherToPairWithBool = undefined  -- What should I do here?

-- | Convert a function from 'Bool' to 'a' to a pair of 'a's. Should be inverse
-- to 'pairToFunctionFromBool'.
functionFromBoolToPair :: (Bool -> a) -> (a,a)
functionFromBoolToPair = error "Not yet implemented: functionFromBoolToPair"

-- | Convert a pair of 'a's to a function from 'Bool' to 'a'. Should be inverse
-- to 'functionFromBoolToPair'.
pairToFunctionFromBool :: (a,a) -> (Bool -> a)
pairToFunctionFromBool = error "Not yet implemented: pairToFunctionFromBool"
```

I don't really know what to do. I know what maybe is, but I think I have a problem with either, because `Either a a` makes no sense in my mind. `Either a b` would be okay. This is either a or b but `Either a a` is `a`?!

I don't have any idea in general how to write these functions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given that I think this is homework, I'll not answer, but give important hints:

If you look for the definitions on hoogle (http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)
you find

```
data Bool = True | False
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

This means that `Bool` can only be `True` or `False`, but that `Either a b` can be `Left a` or `Right b`.

which means your functions should look like

```
pairWithBoolToEither :: (Bool,a) -> Either a a
pairWithBoolToEither (True,a) = ....
pairWithBoolToEither (False,a) = ....
```

and

```
eitherToPairWithBool :: Either a a -> (Bool,a)
eitherToPairWithBool (Left a) = ....
eitherToPairWithBool (Right a) = ....
```

**Comparing with `Maybe`**

`Maybe a` is given by

```
data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

so something of type `Maybe Int` could be `Just 7` or `Nothing`.

Similarly, something of type `Either Int Char` could be `Left 5` or `Right 'c'`.

Something of type `Either Int Int` could be `Left 7` or `Right 4`.

So something with type `Either Int Char` is either an `Int` or a `Char`, but something of type `Either Int Int` is either an `Int` or an `Int`. You don't get to choose anything other than `Int`, but you'll know whether it was a `Left` or a `Right`.

**Why you've been asked this/thinking behind it**

If you have something of type `Either a a`, then the data (eg `5` in `Left 5`) is always of type `a`, and you've just tagged it with `Left` or `Right`. If you have something of type `(Bool,a)` the `a`-data (eg `5` in `(True,5)`) is always the same type, and you've paired it with `False` or `True`.

The maths word for two things which perhaps look different but actually have the same content is "isomorphic". Your instructor has asked you to write a pair of functions which show this isomorphism. Your answer will go down better if `pairWithBoolToEither . eitherToPairWithBool` and `eitherToPairWithBool . pairWithBoolToEither` do what `id` does, i.e. don't change anything. In fact, I've just spotted the comments in your question, where it says they should be inverses. In your write-up, you should show this by doing tests in ghci like

```
ghci> eitherToPairWithBool . pairWithBoolToEither $ (True,'h')
(True,'h')
```

and the other way round.

(In case you haven't seen it, `$` is defined by `f $ x = f x` but `$` has really low precedence (`infixr 0 $`), so `f . g $ x` is `(f . g) $ x` which is just `(f . g) x` and `.` is function composition, so `(f.g) x = f (g x)`. That was a lot of explanation to save one pair of brackets!)

### Functions that take or return functions

This can be a bit mind blowing at first when you're not used to it.

```
functionFromBoolToPair :: (Bool -> a) -> (a,a)
```

The only thing you can pattern match a function with is just a variable like `f`, so we'll need to do something like

```
functionFromBoolToPair f = ...
```

but what can we do with that `f`? Well, the easiest thing to do with a function you're given is to apply it to a value. What value(s) can we use `f` on? Well `f :: (Bool -> a)` so it takes a `Bool` and gives you an `a`, so we can either do `f True` or `f False`, and they'll give us two (probably different) values of type `a`. Now that's handy, because we needed to `a` values, didn't we?

Next have a look at

```
pairToFunctionFromBool :: (a,a) -> (Bool -> a)
```

The pattern match we can do for the type `(a,a)` is something like `(x,y)` so we'll need

```
pairToFunctionFromBool (x,y) = ....
```

but how can we return a function `(Bool -> a)` on the right hand side?

There are two ways I think you'll find easiest. One is to notice that since `->` is right associative anyway, the type `(a,a) -> (Bool -> a)` is the same as `(a,a) -> Bool -> a` so we can actually move the arguments for the function we want to return to before the = sign, like this:

```
pairToFunctionFromBool (x,y) True  = ....
pairToFunctionFromBool (x,y) False = ....
```

Another way, which feels perhaps a little easier, would to make a `let` or `where` clause to define a function called something like `f`, where `f :: Bool -> a`< a bit like:

```
pairToFunctionFromBool (x,y) = f where
  f True = ....
  f False = ....
```

Have fun. Mess around.

Comment: Hints are all I want :-) Maybe I should write that in the opening post. Because I really want to understand. So thank you for your help. I checked hoogle before but i didn't really help. But your patterns are a good start..

Comment: @fuuman Do you get how I was able to go from the definitions to the patterns? That's a key skill, and if not I'll edit in more explanation of that step.

Comment: Thanks for the added information. The compare with maybe and the thinking behind part are very helpful!

Comment: Our instructor gave us two other pairs of functions. And in the documents are always tests. They look like yours ;)  maybeToEitherUnit (eitherUnitToMaybe (Right 'a')) ~?= Right 'a',
    eitherUnitToMaybe (maybeToEitherUnit (Just 5))    ~?= Just 5 So I know what you mean.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it's useful to note that `Either a b` is also called the coproduct, or *sum*, of the types `a` and `b`. Indeed it is now common to use

```
type (+) = Either
```

You can then write `Either a b` as `a + b`.

```
eitherToPairWithBool :: (a+a) -> (Bool,a)
```

Now common sense would dictate that we rewrite `a + a` as something like `2 ⋅ a`. Believe it or not, that is exactly the meaning of the tuple type you're transforming to!

To explain: algebraic data types can roughly be seen as "counting<sup>1</sup> the number of possible constructions". So

```
data Bool = True | False
```

has two constructors. So sort of (this is not valid Haskell!)

```
type 2 = Bool
```

Tuples allow all the combinations of constructors from each argument. So for instance in `(Bool, Bool)`, we have the values

```
      (False,False)
      (False,True )
      (True, False)
      (True, True )
```

You've guessed it: tuples are also called *products*. So the type `(Bool, a)` is basically `2 ⋅ a`: for every value `x :: a`, we can create both the `(False, x)` tuple and the `(True, x)` tuple, alltogether twice as many as there are `x` values.

Much the same thing for `Either a a`: we always have both `Left x` and `Right x` as a possible value.

### All your functions with "arithmetic types":

```
type OnePlus = Maybe

maybeToEitherUnit :: OnePlus a -> () + a
eitherUnitToMaybe :: () + a -> OnePlus a
pairWithBoolToEither :: 2 ⋅ a -> a + a
eitherToPairWithBool :: a + a -> 2 ⋅ a
functionFromBoolToPair :: a² -> a⋅a
pairToFunctionFromBool :: a⋅a -> a²
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>For pretty much any interesting type there are actually infinitely many possible values, still this kind of naïve arithmetic gets you surprisingly far.</sub>

Comment: +1 I love the type arithmetic there. It reminds me of when I taught a lecture course on Cardinality to Mathematics undergraduates. When I used currying as a bijection between (C^B)^A and C^(AxB) it blew their minds. I'm pretty sure none of them were functional programmers.

Answer (score 1):

> `Either a a` makes no sense in my mind.

Yes it does. Try to figure out the difference between type `a` and `Either a a`. `Either` is a [disjoint union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union). Once you understand the difference between `a` and `Either a a`, your homework should be easy in conjunction with AndrewC's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Either a b` means quite literally that a value of such a type can be either an `a`, or an `a`. It sounds like you have actually grasped this concept, but the piece you're missing is that the `Either` type differentiates between values constructed with `Left` and those constructed with `Right`.

For the first part, the idea is that `Maybe` is either `Just` a thing or `Nothing` -- `Nothing` corresponds to `()` because both are "in essence" data types with only one possible value.

The idea behind converting `(Bool, a)` pairs to `Either a a` pairs might seem a little trickier, but just think about the correspondence between `True` and `False` and `Left` and `Right`.

As for converting functions of type `(Bool -> a)` to `(a, a)` pairs, here's a hint: Consider the fact that `Bool` can only have two types, and write down what that initial function argument might look like.

Hopefully those hints help you to get started.

Comment: (Bool -> a) to (a, a) is my biggest problem. The rest is okay now. I mean, I get a function as input? What does that look like? I have no idea to do that. Thanks so far!

Comment: @fuuman Well, you'll have a function that looks like "`f True = someA`, `f False = someOtherA`", and you're feeding that into a function like this: `functionFromBoolToPair f`. What can you do to get two different `a`s from this function?

Comment: @fuuman If I give you a function that only has two possible inputs and two possible outputs, how can you get both possible outputs? Think of a mathematical function f(0) = x, f(1) = y. How can you get both x, and y, given the function f?

Comment: I would take the two possible inputs and put them into the function. Then I will get both possible outputs. So pattern matching is the right move here? But I cant handle this high order function at the moment.. with a function as a input.. :\ Sorry, but functional programming is not my favorite :D Thinking still to OO.

Comment: @fuuman You can pass functions around like regular arguments, so if you have a function like I described above named `f`, you can pass it directly into `functionFromBoolToPair` and use it like any old function in the body like so: `functionFromBoolToPair f = f ???`.